# Firefox CSS table-cell inner div incorrect

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, css-tables

I have a table set up using CSS like this:

```
<div id="page" class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="project" id="project-id">
                <a class="fancybox" rel="project-id" href="project-id/image.jpg"><img src="project-id/image.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are 4 `<div class="cell">` in the row, and there are 4 rows. This displays correctly in Safari, Chrome, and Opera. I can't test on IE right now as I don't have a Windows computer but when I get the chance I will...

I uploaded the page to this URL: http://schdri.comuv.com/

It will take a long time to load so please give it some time!
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Please include the relevant CSS in your question. You can also use something like jsFiddle to demonstrate exactly what you're trying to achieve here...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the `<table>` tag instead? It should work in all browsers and is easily formatted in CSS.

```
<table>
    <tr> <!-- table row -->
        <td> <!-- table cell -->
            <!-- cell content here -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

*You can see the `<table>` spec [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html).*